# What is the time complexity of determining maximal overlaps between bitmap images?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, suffix-trees, digital-image-processing

Given two bitmap images (two arbitrarily sized two-dimensional matrices of integer values ranging from 0 to some maximum number), I want to determine their maximum overlaps.

An overlap is a relative positioning of the images (a translation of the second image) producing a nonempty intersection on which both images are the same.

For instance, the images
$\left\langle
  \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix},
  \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\right\rangle$
have overlaps
$\{ (1,-1), (1,0), (1,1) \}$, with intersection sizes $1,2,1$, respectively, so only $(1,0)$ is maximal.

It seems to me we can create a fast algorithm based on generalizing suffix trees to "subimage trees", built with a floodfill algorithm.

Is this a viable approach?  Is it better than alternatives?

Is this problem discussed in the literature?  What is its time complexity?

(My apologies for asking several related questions at once.)

Comment: What is "subimage trees"? I couldn't find information of this by searching.

Comment: What I mean is a 2D version of a suffix tree. Instead of mapping each substrings of a string to the positions in the string where they occur, it would map subimages of the original images to the 2D positions where they occur. I'm being vague because I haven't actually tried to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

For a pair of matrices $A, B$, $B$ maximally overlaps $A$ at a position if and only if certain two rectangular sub-matrices of $A$ and $B$ match.

It is not clear how to use the *two-dimensional suffix tree* for this problem, because this data structure can only process **square** sub-matrix matching queries.

An answer is to use the fingerprinting-based algorithm. By generalizing [Rabin-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), any rectangular sub-matrix pattern matching query can be answered in constant time.

More specifically, a matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times m}$ is represented by a fingerprint $h(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m A_{i,j} X^{i-1} Y^{j-1}$ in two randomly-chosen variables $X, Y$ in a big enough finite field. By pre-computing all "prefix" values of forms $h(A[1:i,1:j])$ and $X^iY^j$, any fingerprint of a rectangular sub-matrix can be computed in constant time.

Comment: You're right, the linked problem is different. I've removed the reference. I am looking for exact matching, not approximate matching.

Comment: I have rewritten the answer for the updated question.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this looks very useful.